# Android switching button - green to red

Tags: android, android-button

How to make a button which when pressed turns green, and after key again to red.

Comment: read this post this may be helpful to you. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: You should use `selectors`. Follow the link given by @Akshay, there's a simple tutorial demonstrating the creation and use of selectors.

Comment: @Akshay 's solution is best. To add a touch listener will be overhead.

Comment: Yes but I need that was red and changed only when pressed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {

    final int action = event.getAction();

        if(view.getId()==R.id.yourButton){
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                  yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_button_green);
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                  yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_button_red);
        }

 }
```